# Which Java technology should I use, if I want to build a website with thousands of users?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Sorry for asking this question, but I searched all Java-related questions, but I got more confused. I am still not clear what should I start with.

1. My main thing is building websites in Java, because someone told me that there are some [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) or AI libraries available in Java which I can use in Java. So I decided to use that as it can reduce my work.

Now I don't know Java at all. Some people say the following are used to build websites, like:

1. [Servlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) alone can build a website
2. [JSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) alone can also build a website
3. [Struts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)
4. [Spring Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) with [Hibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)
5. [Seam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)
6. [Java EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) also for websites

I am confused. Where should I start from? Where does core Java fits in here?

I was thinking of perhaps learning [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) as I know I have to learn Python only, not its variations.

So please guide me to one thing which can solve my basic purpose of using ready-made libraries of AI.

If I can do that with JSP then I will start with that.
But if I need to learn all of them, then it’s better if can start learning Python.

I have five months to finish the website.

I really don't know why there are many branches of Java for doing one thing.

Comment: If you have 5 months to finish a website and need to learn everything (from the view to the persistence layer) in the same time, you'll need some on site guidance IMO.

Comment: so how much time u think will be enough for that , i can discuss with my boss about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To correct some misconceptions of yours:

- servlets and JSP are Java EE
- Seam and Struts can be used together with Hibernate as well
- Spring MVC is a web framework. Spring as a [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) framework can be used together with any other framework.
- there are many more options, like [JSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces), [Tapestry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tapestry), [Click](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Click), [Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tapestry), etc.

It depends on what will the site will be doing, but you can choose any.

Comment: i need to build a ecommerce website with recommendation system like amazon.com . What should go for

Comment: My personal preference goes to Spring MVC or JSF.

Comment: sorry for being dumb , is SPRING MVC or JSF different from java. so it means first i should do core java and then get book on SPring MVC or JSF , no need for servlets or jsp

Comment: you'd need to learn jsp anyway, because Spring MVC uses it as a view technology.

Comment: 1 question when making a portal is it the same as making a web site when using struts 2 framework?sorry for a question like this im just a new programmer so i need to be sure if im doing everything the right way

Answer (score 4):

Experience has shown that building complex HTML forms (especially validation) and Ajax functionality is hard to get right. You will most likely appreciate having a library to assist you with that.  The same thing with database access.

Everything builds on servlets. Learn those in order to understand the libraries you *will* use.

I would suggest learning [JavaServer Faces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) (JSF) with facelets. The easiest, while being powerful, is JSF 2 in Java EE 6. The easiest way to get started is to use [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) with [GlassFish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish) 3.

Comment: wait a minute i am going mad , Glass fish is langauge or what. Please can anyone guide in a flow chart like how should i go from scratch to final website like   1)Learn core java 2)Learn Servlets 3)JSF2 4)facets 5)netbeans 6)Glassfish 7)Site ready

Comment: @Mirage.  Yes, the learning curve is somewhat steep.  You _will_ need know the Java language pretty well as all layers use that.  The Java Tutorial is pretty nice and even has a servlet section:  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/

Comment: @Mirage.  Start with Core Java - everything else depends on that.  Java Tutorial (online) and Head First Java (book) are great resources.

Answer (score 4):

For static web pages, HTML alone is enough and if you want to make it more user-friendly and interactive, use JavaScript.

There are lot of frameworks you can use directly in JavaScript, like [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). Now *if* you want to make some more functionalities, like database interaction, then you will need either [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), Java ([JSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Server_Pages) and [Servlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet)) or [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC) (there exist some more, but I’m aware of three only). Each of them have their library to interact with database.

Since you are interested in Java, go through Servlets, HTML, JavaScript, and JSP. Once this is done, you can look into JSF and [EJB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBean) beans. So *if* you have knowledge of Java this will not take too much time, because the syntax is the same; the only difference is the concept.

So you will have a frontend (HTML, JS, and JSP) which will interact with the backend (Servlets and the database) which will be deployed in a Web container. To deploy, you can use an one of the available application servers, like [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat), [GlassFish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish), or [WebSphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere). To develop your application, you can use [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) as the IDE, which is one of the best IDEs I have used.

So decide your architecture and design, break it into components and start writing small applications first. Once you are experienced in small application, start writing an application where there are more things you have to care of, like load on database, availability, security, etc. For that, you can refer a very famous question on Stack Overflow, *[What technical details should a programmer of a web application consider before making the site public?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-technical-details-should-a-programmer-of-a-web-application-consider-before)*.

Comment: So i will first learn simple java programs and then servlets and jsp. Then after making some basic site using that , i should move on JSF2

Comment: IMHO you should do that, directly writing website with thousand users will not be suggested. First get your hands on initial web development and then get into the deep details and concerns like security, load etc. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The closest to core Java is servlets. No extra syntax, very minimal library, but no included functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For building websites, the main thing is HTML and HTTP.

All technologies (including Enterprise Java or Server side Java) do the same—to understand an HTTP request and respond back with HTML. All that you mentioned do the same thing with a different level of sophistication.

Start with Wikipedia.org to know what technologies do what. If you are completely new to Java, go through the [Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems#Java_platform) tutorials, do sample programs, and get comfortable with Java packages, JVM and classes. (This might take a week or two).

To build websites using Java, you'll have to learn Java Servlets—everything else (JSP, Struts, JSF, and Spring(!)) are built on it. Get *[Head First](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_First_(book_series))* books on Java and Servlets; they will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can always build the page in [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) [or something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) that will give you a website very fast. For the AI stuff that analyzes the bought items for the recommendations, use something unrelated to the page that only takes the database to work with.

I would not mix the whole web page stuff with the AI computing. You can do the AI things that will take a long time and maybe should done on a different machine to have your webpage also responsive with C++ or Java in normal applications.

Choosing your front end technique because of later usage is a very dangerous thing. Using the whole Java EE concept and learning it from scratch will take you much longer than have a quick start with your page if you do it in Ruby or [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP).

You can then build the first version of the page and generate a user base. Start working on the AI stuff once you got some data with other technologies.

If your page has performance problems because your technology does not scale, you can always begin switching parts of the stuff out with a faster technology or maybe simply a bigger machine. Get your page running before you build it bulletproof for the thousand users you are expecting.

Comment: If you are new to Java and has a 5 month deadline, I would strongly recommend that you tell your boss you need a mentor, or the team needs an experienced Java developer

Comment: I did a project with Java knowledge and i could not hold my 7 month deadline. We also did a project in ruby without ruby knowledge and got it working in 5 month. JavaEE is hard to get right at the first time and I would say it has a hard and steady learning curve

Comment: Actually i have to complete this project from home , so i am fully at home all six months, so i can devote around 15hours per day

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to build a website from scratch, with no prior knowledge, your best bet is to go with frameworks that provide a complete stack for web development.

If you aren't dead set on Java, you could probably start learning [Ruby on Rails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails), which would be easier to start with (if so, go buy a [Ruby on Rails tutorial](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321743121) which goes through all the necessary things for modern web development, from [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to version control).

For Java, try:

- [Play Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_Framework) is very similar to Ruby on Rails. It will get you started very quickly, and hopefully (if you follow conventions) handle all of your peripheral needs.
- [Spring Roo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Roo) is a very-fast-to-work-with framework, but it might get hard to maintain and extend later on.

These two are full web frameworks, that is, they handle database, MVC (presentation layer), configuration setting, etc... (I'll explain shortly). And could even ease your deployment process.

If you're going to go through any other route (using several frameworks together), you are probably not going to finish what you are doing in five months.

To understand why, and to clear some things you wrote in your question, you need to understand that modern web development (and enterprise development as a whole) is comprised of several different technologies:

- Presentation: the term web frameworks has been more or less taken to mean frameworks that deal with this side of web development, i.e., how to create a web page (an HTML page). Most of the frameworks offer an MVC like approach (which you can read about elsewhere), and this is what most of the frameworks/technologies you gave sit in—[JSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Server_Pages) and [Struts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts) (which uses JSP) are examples of web frameworks. [Servlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet) is a lower-level API that standardizes how to answer HTTP requests (which JSP and Struts sit on top of).
- Persistence: being able to show a webpage doesn't mean squat these days if you can't save data to a database, and that is what the persistence frameworks do (they ease the way you can save data to the database). [Hibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) is a persistence framework.
- For Java there are also [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI), which is what Spring DI is. It's tough to explain DI to people not familiar with the troubles of Java, so I won't try to explain it, but it's a very important part of modern Java development.
- apart from these core technologies, there are also many items that you'll need to learn to actually deploy the application (unless your using services like [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) or [Google App Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine), which should simplify things), and troubleshoot it later (understanding how concurrency and HTTP works).

To address the other technologies you brought up:

- I've never really touched Seam, so I'm not sure, but it looks like a collection of other frameworks (*mainly* [EJB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBean) 3, which itself is a collection of APIs, and JSF).
- Spring denotes a popular open source group (the SpringSource group) that provides various technologies, but most likely when you hear about it they refer to two things Spring's dependency injection (DI) and Spring's MVC (which is a web framework).
- Java EE is merely a collection of high level APIs which other technologies implement (Hibernate implements [JPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) which is part of Java EE for instance).